# Loading details into fragment causes An operation is not implemented error

Tags: android, kotlin, android-viewmodel

I have this code in a fragment controller, all runs okey until

```
crimeDetailViewModel.loadCrime(crimeId)
```

This generates this error

> kotlin.NotImplementedError: An operation is not implemented: Not yet
> implemented at
> com.bignerdranch.android.criminalintent.CrimeFragment$onStart$titleWatcher$1.beforeTextChanged(CrimeFragment.kt:116)

I thought it is about the ViewModel version because i hook it up like this

```
private val crimeDetailViewModel : CrimeDetailViewModel by lazy { ViewModelProvider(this).get(CrimeDetailViewModel::class.java) }
```

but this same way i use with the crimelist and it is pulling data as needed

```
private val crimeListViewModel: CrimeListViewModel by lazy { ViewModelProvider(this).get(CrimeListViewModel::class.java) }
```

> → I/CrimeListFragment: Got Crimes 100

I tried to debug it. I found that it gets the crimeID correctly… but getting the crime to be displayed using the load function `crimeDetailViewModel.loadCrime(crimeId)` generated that error…

```
import android.os.Bundle
import android.text.Editable
import android.text.TextWatcher
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.widget.Button
import android.widget.CheckBox
import android.widget.EditText
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment
import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider
import com.bignerdranch.android.criminalintent.database.CrimeDetailViewModel
import java.util.*
import androidx.lifecycle.Observer

private const val ARG_CRIME_ID = "crime_id"
class CrimeFragment: Fragment() {
    private lateinit var crime: Crime
    private lateinit var titleField: EditText
    private lateinit var dateButton: Button
    private lateinit var solvedCheckBox: CheckBox
   
    private val crimeDetailViewModel : CrimeDetailViewModel by lazy {
        ViewModelProvider(this).get(CrimeDetailViewModel::class.java)
    }

  
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        crime = Crime()
        
        val crimeId: UUID = arguments?.getSerializable(ARG_CRIME_ID) as UUID
       
        crimeDetailViewModel.loadCrime(crimeId)  <--- this line is where the app crash
    }

  
    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        val view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_crime, container,false)

        titleField = view.findViewById(R.id.crime_title) as EditText
        dateButton = view.findViewById(R.id.crime_date) as Button
        solvedCheckBox = view.findViewById(R.id.crime_solved) as CheckBox

        dateButton.apply {
            text = crime.date.toString()
            isEnabled = false
        }

        return view
    }

  
    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        crimeDetailViewModel.crimeLiveData.observe(
            viewLifecycleOwner,
            Observer { crime ->
                crime?.let {
                    this.crime = crime
                    updateUI()
                }
            }
        )
    }

    override fun onStart() {
        super.onStart()
       
        val titleWatcher = object : TextWatcher{
            override fun beforeTextChanged(s: CharSequence?,
                                           start: Int,
                                           count: Int,
                                           after: Int) {
                TODO("Not yet implemented")  <-- error points to this line
            }

            override fun onTextChanged(s: CharSequence?,
                                       start: Int,
                                       before: Int,
                                       count: Int) {
                crime.title = s.toString()
            }

            override fun afterTextChanged(s: Editable?) {
                TODO("Not yet implemented")
            }
        }
        titleField.addTextChangedListener(titleWatcher)

        solvedCheckBox.apply {
            setOnCheckedChangeListener { _, isChecked ->
                crime.isSolved = isChecked
            }
        }
    }

    
    private fun updateUI() {
        titleField.setText(crime.title)
        dateButton.text = crime.date.toString()
        solvedCheckBox.isChecked = crime.isSolved
    }

    
    companion object{
        fun newInstance(crimeId: UUID):CrimeFragment{
            val args = Bundle().apply{
                putSerializable(ARG_CRIME_ID,crimeId)
                /* we can pass any argument and put it in Bundle,
                using the instance from parent activity
                 */
            }
            return CrimeFragment().apply {
                arguments = args
            }
        }
    }

   override fun onStop() {
        super.onStop()
        crimeDetailViewModel.saveCrime(crime)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `TODO` function throws a `NotImplementedError`. See https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/-t-o-d-o.html . Just remove the `TODO` function and it won't crash. Those functions are added by default to remind you to implement the method. In this case, though, there is nothing to do in that callback so you can simply remove it from that method and any others you intend to leave blank.

```
        val titleWatcher = object : TextWatcher {
            override fun beforeTextChanged(
                s: CharSequence,
                start: Int,
                count: Int,
                after: Int
            ) = Unit

            override fun onTextChanged(
                s: CharSequence?,
                start: Int,
                before: Int,
                count: Int
            ) {
                crime.title = s.toString()
            }

            override fun afterTextChanged(s: Editable) = Unit
        }
```